# Is it OK to use perfect infinitive in such cases...?

Tags: perfect-infinitive

I wanted to express my disdain for certaing people and say something along the lines of ***"If they by any chance were to die tomorrow, I wouldn't care"*** (I know it's a wrong thing to say, and I'm sorry.) What I actually said was:

***They could have been killed tomorrow; I couldn't care less.***

Shouldn't I have said: ***They could be killed...***? I used the perfect infinitive to emphasize the improbability of them being killed any time soon. Now I feel I overdid it.

Comment: More simply (and I think more commonly) _They could get killed tomorrow and I couldn't care less/wouldn't care._ In emphatic phraseology, simpler is shorter is more memorable is better.

Comment: Incorrect use of the present-perfect tense "have been".  1: The time cannot be exact, so "tomorrow" defeats it.  2: The event would have occurred in the past, not he future.  "They could have been killed; I wouldn't have cared less."  Keeping it as close to the original as possible:  "They could be killed tomorrow [; I couldn't care less.]" [and I would not care.] [for all I care.]

Comment: One more comment.  If you go with your corrected response, a semicolon does not sufficiently explain the relationship between the two independent thoughts.  The coordinating conjunction "and" would do better.  "He could be killed tomorrow, and I couldn't care less." The time differential is the reason:  {He could die tomorrow. [;] I could not care right now.}  {He could die tomorrow. [, and] I could not care right now.}

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not about the present perfect tense and the lack of exact time. If it were, we couldn't say: "You shouldn't have done it yesterday", and I feel it's quite correct.

Comment: To quote my favorite online resource for perfect tense, "We use the Present Perfect to say that an action happened at an unspecified time before now. The exact time is not important. You CANNOT use the Present Perfect with specific time expressions such as: yesterday, one year ago, last week, when I was a child, when I lived in Japan, at that moment, that day, one day, etc. We CAN use the Present Perfect with unspecific expressions such as: ever, never, once, many times, several times, before, so far, already, yet, etc. " http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html

Comment: That being said, adding subjunctive tense makes it so that @jules it does not happen at a specific times. We could not state, "I had been sad yesterday."  You COULD state, "I COULD have been sad yesterday." because it removes the exactness of time.  I am really tired of people pretending we should go by what "sounds" right to us.  These things have very simple rules.  I was simply outlining the rules for perfect tense since that was his question.

Comment: The "have been" in the example is not a tense, it's a perfect infinitive without "to". Could" changes jack. "You can't speak English." "You can't be speaking English." "You can't have spoken English." are - syntactically - the same structure - modal + infinitive. TENSE: A set of forms taken by a verb to indicate the time (and sometimes also the continuance or completeness) of the action in relation to the time of the utterance. 
INFINITIVE: The basic form of a verb, without an inflection binding it to a particular subject or tense (e.g.see in we came to see, let him see

Comment: PS. I'm really at a loss on what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Cf. Swan M. (2005). Practical English Usage. p. 264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did overdo it.  Tomorrow is not a point in the past, however you stretch the imagination, and you are using something perfect where the point of completion is tomorrow.  As noted below, that could happen, but would be totally unrelated to what you meant.

You could render it on-topic, but very strange, by putting 'by' in front of tomorrow, making it future perfect.  But as stated, it simply doesn't mean what you want to say.

Your correction is OK.  But you should consider 'may' or 'might' when you want 'could' to denote possibility rather than ability, especially in the future.  "She may be killed tomorrow; I couldn't care less" feels less cramped.

Comment: Er, *"They could have been killed tomorrow. You knew they were planning to go camping in the mountains. You didn't have to kill them today, especially not in my kitchen. Now I gotta clean up this mess!"*

Comment: OK, you are right, it was already grammatically correct, but very strange, just in a way totally unrelated to his intent.  English knows so few bounds, and so many back-alleys.

Comment: Also, *"They could have been killed tomorrow."* isn't a present-perfect or a past-perfect.

Comment: Edited to acknowledge these comments.  The have definitely makes it perfect, so I don't see how it can be neither past nor present perfect.

Comment: It's neither past-perfect nor present-perfect because the "have" in that sentence is in the plain form due to being the complement of the modal auxiliary "could". And so, that "have" does not have a primary tense.

Comment: @F.E. "
   
 
Also, "They could have been killed tomorrow." isn't a present-perfect or a past-perfect. –  F.E" LOL!  Actually "have been" IS present-perfect tense--it is not a discussion. ;)  'could' is simply an axillary verb making it conditional.  Your comments always make me smile. ;)  By the way, "Isn't present perfect", not "Isn't a present perfect."  Have a nice day!

Comment: @APrejean You are wrong, as usual.

Comment: OK, my grammar is old-fashioned, but not I am not stupid.  The 'could' here is a marker of subjunctive, since we are talking about something potentially contrary to fact.  Since it marks subjunctive it remains present instead of past (Like "If I were wrong...")  So I was wrong about the double past, since 'could' is not, here, the past tense of 'can'.  But "could have" then still has to be perfect, right?

Comment: @JonJayObermark You are correct; it is still perfect.  F.E. feels like he has to contradict me in endless ad hominem attacks without logic or reason. I am running. Present progressive.  I could be running. Still present progressive,  Have been = present perfect.   Could have been = still present perfect.

Comment: In *"They could have been killed tomorrow"*, the "have been" is a perfect. But since the "have" is not tensed (because a tensed verb is not allowed after the "could" here), that is really all you can call it: *perfect tense*. Or maybe call it "non-tensed perfect" or something like that.

Comment: OK, so someone is insisting that instead of present subjunctive English has only an absolute subjunctive.  Seems like an excuse to pick on old people, to me...

Comment: @JonJayObermark And I was so hoping that you would make a comment about his so-called "'non-tensed' perfect".  We no longer need verb tenses, guys!

Comment: Actually, I'm staring at a grammar textbook that discusses this issue. *"The perfect in clauses without primary tense. The third case to consider is where auxiliary* ***have*** *appears in a secondary form, so that there is no primary (inflectional) tense."* It uses as examples: *"We believe her to have been in Bonn at the time." "Having reached agreement yesterday, we don't need to meet today."* -- 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*.

Comment: @F.E. You are aware that that is functioning as an infinitive (no longer a verb) and that is what he is referring to?  Oh wait... if you did, you wouldn't have posted it.  "believe" is the main verb--simple present.  /tickles you  In the second sentence, "Having reached agreement yesterday," is a participial phrase (also no longer acting like a verb).  You just referred to "perfect tense" being used in verbals"  /tickles you again.

Comment: OK, so I will.  There are languages with non-tenses.  One of the special uses of the aorist in Greek implies something has always been and always will be true.  You can consider that a non-tensed perfect, if you really, really want to.  It is not in progress.

But English grammar in my day always stuck with the idea that free tenses were implicitly present.  So we had a present subjunctive, even though it was more 'absent' than 'present'.

Comment: @JonJayObermark Just read his last comment.  He is confusing verbals with verbs.  I love your last comment.  Where do you teach?

Comment: I'm not making this stuff up. This is stuff from the two major authors of the 2002 reference grammar *CGEL*.

Comment: @F.E. Please take a second to read this.  "to have been in Bonn" is an infinitive phrase, a verbal, and it can act as either a noun, an adjective, or an adverb, but it is no longer a verb.  "Having reached agreement yesterday" is a participial phrase, a verbal, which acts like an adjective, but it is no longer a verb.  That is what is being referenced in your textbook.

Comment: @APrejean: I don't.  I used to teach remedial math and logic and Columbia College in Chicago for a bit, but now I am a programmer.  I just loved Classics, and in order to read Latin and Greek, you actually have to learn English grammar.

Comment: @F.E. I understand how modern linguistics needs to rename all the stuff we are used to, in an attempt to get all grammars in the same terms.  But in a more English-specific sense, that does not make the older way of looking at this wrong, just narrow.

Comment: @JonJayObermark You are a polymath, Sir.  My deepest respects.

Comment: OK, but if you formulate the expression of the English present subjunctive as a modal verb in an apparently past tense, with the primary verb expressed as an infinitive, then we are all drawing closer to agreeing.  It is superficially pluperfect, since could is officially the past of can, but stripping that off because it is subjunctive it ends up as a present perfect, and if you are focussed on the main verb as an infinitive, it loses the ability to hold tense, although it retains perfective aspect.

Comment: @F.E.  So I get to needle you back: It has a name.  You still cannot call it perfect *tense* if you are narrowly focused on the part of the verb after the 'could'.

In a more global grammatical context it has a name, it is called perfect (or perfective) aspect.

Comment: Well, er, it ain't my name for it. That's what *CGEL* calls it. They consider the perfect to be a secondary past-tense. *shrugs* -- So, don't blame me for that; blame them (they also call it "non-finite perfect"). You can easily see that the "have" isn't tensed: consider *"He could* ***has*** *been killed tomorrow"* is ungrammatical, and *"He could* ***had*** *been killed tomorrow"* is ungrammatical, and then use "BE", as in *"They could* ***be*** *killed tomorrow"* which definitely uses the plain form verb "be", not a past-tense or present-tense form. Thus, the "have" is also plain form.

Comment: @F.E. I am sure that is not true.  If something cannot take a tense, according to their own rules I am quite certain that what it has is not called perfect tense.  No one is quite that jargonesque, even among English grammarians.

Comment: Even traditional grammars say that "have" in that example is not tensed. Many of them call it an "infinitive verb" or even "base form". I'm looking at one such textbook now-- "Modals are helping verbs. They are quite limited in how they can be used. Modals can never be used alone. They can only be used in combination with a following verb in the base form, for example (modals in italics, base verbs in bold): You *can* **do** it. They *must* **be** careful. You *should* **know** better." -- And so, this is nothing new; it is not something new to modern grammar or to *CGEL*.

Comment: @F.E. We are not talking about 'have' we are talking about the whole verb  "could have been killed".  Look at what you *actually said* to which we took exception.  """They could have been killed tomorrow." isn't a present-perfect or a past-perfect"""

Whether or not 'have' is tensed, the rest of the verb *is*.  If you want to discuss something other than **what you actually said**, then arrange to have said something different.

Comment: Why don't you simply open up your favorite grammar book and see what it says?

Comment: Primary example fully conjugated contains "They might have been loved" as Third person, passive, subjunctive, present perfect.  It is an exact parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The **perfect infinitive** can refer to something that will be completed at a point in the future:

We hope to have finished the building works by the end of March.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked

Answer (score 0):

The correct degree of insouciance would be rendered by "if they dropped dead tomorrow, I wouldn't (care/shed a tear/lose any sleep)". A fussier grammarian would say "if they were to drop dead . . " but such sentiments are rarely voiced in a formal style.

There are a few such ready-made expressions, with perhaps the best one describing how little trouble you would go to if you saw them on fire :-)